RedisTimeoutException when using RedisSessionStateProvider on a .NET 4.8 ASP.Net site to store sessionState in Azure Redis Cache
I am getting this error when using Azure Redis cache to store statesessions in a .NET 4.8 ASP.NET page

It is like the sessions aren't being closed properly, I can see in the metrics that the gets to the cache is insanely high sometimes over 20.000 each minute.

If I flushall on the cache it works again.
I tried to add UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext and set httpRuntime to 4.0 like they say here, but it haven't solved the issue.
https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/973#issuecomment-581043573
I tried to scale the cache to a Standard C3 with 6GB and up to 5.000 connections with moderate network bandwidth, without any improvements.
I have configured the RedisSessionStateProvider on the website like this
 <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
   <providers>
    <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" connectionString="xxxx,password=yyyy=,ssl=False,abortConnect=False" />
    </providers>
 </sessionState>

Thanks

I created a sample ASP .Net 4.8 application with Azure redis cache.
For saving the state sessions in Azure Redis Cache without any issue, set the following values in your connection string configuration.
I've included the following

connectTimeout=15000 and syncTimeout=10000, this will ensure that the application waits for connections and thus avoiding timeouts.
Also added asyncTimeout=10000 for asynchronous operations to avoid timeout errors.
kept ssl=true for secure connections.

configuration of RedisSessionStateProvider:
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
    <providers>
        <add name="MySessionStateStore"          
        type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
            connectionString="redis24.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=<password>,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,connectTimeout=15000,syncTimeout=10000,asyncTimeout=10000" />
    </providers>
</sessionState>

complete web.config:
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
            </namespaces>
            <controls>
                <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
            <providers>
                <add name="MySessionStateStore"                     type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"                     connectionString="redis24.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=<password>,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,connectTimeout=15000,syncTimeout=10000,asyncTimeout=10000" />
            </providers>
        </sessionState>
    </system.web>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.IO.Pipelines" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.2" newVersion="6.0.0.2" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Channels" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=&quot;Web&quot; /optionInfer+" />
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="Session" />
            <add name="Session" type="Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModuleAsync, Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModule, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

output:




Why do you think this will solve the issue? The configuration I have now also works, but it starts throwing the timeout, if I clear the cache it works again, we don't have any issues in the QA environment, so I think this is caused when multiple users are connected, when I check how many is connected to redis cache when it fails it says 16.
